# Confusion between "#define clear()" and "std::wstring::clear()"

Tags: c++

I included "PDCurses/curses.h" which defined a function 'clear()', then when I use 'std::wstring::clear()' the msvc-10.0 compiler reports errors. It's fixed when I '#undef clear()' after including. The code is like this:

```
inline void str_clear( std::wstring& wstr ) 
{
    wstr.clear();
}
```

I used 'std::' but why the compiler is still confusing? 
May It be caused by multi-defined 'namespace'?

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't care about types or namespaces, it blindly replaces stuff. `clear()` is a crappy macro to put in a header though.

Comment: If it is a `#define`, then it will just replace `clear( ... )` by something else before compilation.

Comment: It can also be avoided by rewriting the code in such a way that `clear()` does not appear literally, for example like `(wstr.clear)()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is because the preprocessor basically does a search-and-replace on all macros that are defined. And it's done before the compiler proper gets the code, and it does not know anything about namespaces, classes or scope in general.

So if you have e.g.

```
#define clear()  something
```

and then use

```
wstr.clear();
```

The preprocessor will replace the `clear()` so that the compiler sees

```
wstr.something;
```

Comment: The compiler do not search from the type of 'wstr' ?

Comment: @NFDream: The compiler would; but macros are expanded by the preprocessor which knows nothing about types, scopes, or any other aspect of the language syntax. It simply replaces tokens with other tokens before the compiler does anything.

Comment: And this is why you should stay clear of macros if possible. This is also way many C/C++ books advice you to create separate namespace for macros by naming them ALL UPPERCASE.